# just starting to learn c for loop

Tags: c

I am supposed to make a dice game that plays multiple times.  I am not really looking for the answer, kind of looking to see what I am doing wrong.  I would expect the for loop to assign the int i a value of 0, then run the dice rolls, then add one to *i*, until *i* is > 50.  Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main(){
int rollDie1, rollDie2, keyValue = 0, win = 0, lose = 0, reroll = 0, i;
srand(time(NULL));  // call this only once – seed the random generator

for (i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i++);
{
rollDie1 = rand() % 6 + 1;  // in the range of 1 - 6
rollDie2 = rand() % 6 + 1;  // in the range of 1 - 6
keyValue = rollDie1 + rollDie2;



    if ( keyValue == 7 || keyValue == 11 )
    {
    printf ("Player wins on the first roll \n");
    }


    if ( keyValue == 2 || keyValue == 3 || keyValue == 12 )
    {
    printf("Sorry, you lost on the first roll \n");
    }

    if (  keyValue == 4 || keyValue == 5 || keyValue == 6 || keyValue == 8 || keyValue == 9 || keyValue == 10 ) 
    {
    printf("Reroll! \n");
    }
}

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Looks a lot like craps, but different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a `;` at the end of the for loop that shouldn't be there.

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i++);
```

should be

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i++)
```

otherwise there is nothing in the for-loop and what's in the `{}` will only be executed once, as that's a separate statement.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I always make that mistake and never see it.

Answer (score 3):

You have a semicolon at the end of the loop:

`for (i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i++);`

So it does nothing 50 times.  You simply need to remove the semicolon so that your brackets `{}` will actually encapsulate the lines of your code that are supposed to be in the for loop. 
 If you don't have an open bracket `{` immediately following a for loop, the first complete statement following the for loop will be executed at each iteration.  The semicolon is a complete statement that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it will run as long as i<50 which is from 0 to 49

Comment: thank you, it was the semicolon at the end of the for loop that was the problem.

Comment: Yes, it was, just wanted to add this detail